# how to convert <class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'> to JSON in python using builtin operator json.dumps

Tags: json, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

how do i convert  to json format,

i am getting an error  "is not JSON serializable"

following is my program

```
from urllib2 import urlopen as uReq
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import requests
import json
my_url='https://uae.dubizzle.com/en/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/?filters=(neighborhoods.ids=123)&amp;page=1'

uClient=uReq(my_url)
page_html= uClient.read()
page_soup=BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')
comments = page_soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
[comment.extract() for comment in comments]
json_output= page_soup.find_all("script",type="application/ld+json",string=re.compile("SingleFamilyResidence")) #find_all("script", "application/ld+json")
#comments = json_output.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
#[comment.extract() for comment in comments]
#json_output.find_all(text="<script type=""application/ld+json"">").replaceWith("")
#print json_output
jsonD = json.dumps(json_output)
uClient.close()
```

[{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"SingleFamilyResidence","name":"Spacious 2BHK For Rent in Damascus Street Al Qusais","url":"https://dubai.dubizzle.com/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/2018/4/29/spacious-two-bed-room-available-for-rent-i-2/","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","addressLocality":"Dubai","addressRegion":"Dubai"},"":{"@type":"Product","name":"Spacious 2BHK For Rent in Damascus Street Al Qusais","url":"https://dubai.dubizzle.com/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/2018/4/29/spacious-two-bed-room-available-for-rent-i-2/","offers":{"@type":"Offer","price":49000,"priceCurrency":"AED"}},"floorSize":1400,"numberOfRooms":2,"image":"https://dbzlpvfeeds-a.akamaihd.net/images/user_images/2018/04/29/80881784_CP_photo.jpeg","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":55.3923,"longitude":25.2893}}, {"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"SingleFamilyResidence","name":"Fully Furnished  2 Bed Room Flat -Al Qusais","url":"https://dubai.dubizzle.com/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/2017/10/9/fully-furnished-brand-new-2-bed-room-flat--2/","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","addressLocality":"Dubai","addressRegion":"Dubai"},"":{"@type":"Product","name":"Fully Furnished  2 Bed Room Flat -Al Qusais","url":"https://dubai.dubizzle.com/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/2017/10/9/fully-furnished-brand-new-2-bed-room-flat--2/","offers":{"@type":"Offer","price":70000,"priceCurrency":"AED"}},"floorSize":1400,"numberOfRooms":2,"image":"https://dbzlpvfeeds-a.akamaihd.net/images/user_images/2018/09/05/84371522_CP_photo.jpeg","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":55.3959,"longitude":25.2959}}]

Comment: You have to replace `script` tag before `json.dumps()`

Answer (score 0):

Hi Added another wrapper of BeautifulSoup and got the expected json by

first getting text and using .get_text() Method and second using json.loads

thank you intelligentsia.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen as uReq
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import requests
import json
my_url='https://uae.dubizzle.com/en/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/?filters=(neighborhoods.ids=123)&amp;page=1'

uClient=uReq(my_url)
page_html= uClient.read()
page_soup=BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'lxml')# 'html.parser')
json_output= BeautifulSoup(str(page_soup.find_all("script",type="application/ld+json",string=re.compile("SingleFamilyResidence"))), 'lxml')#find_all("script", "application/ld+json")
json_text=json_output.get_text()
json_data = json.loads(json_text)
print json_data
uClient.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

first convert bs4.element.ResultSet to string after that change to json

```
json_data = json.dumps(str(json_output))
```